# Retrieve Kth lexicographically smallest string from trie tree

Tags: java, trie, lexicographic

I am currently trying to solve a problem which involves retreiving kth lexicographically smallest string from a trie.

Example: let us consider the following set of strings: {"a", "b", "c", "aa", "aab", "ab", "ac", "aac"}. Next, lets say that I am required to find 3rd smallest string from the set. In that case, the result should be "aab".

I am using trie based implementation for the same because the set of strings can be very large and there can be many queries asking to find kth smallest strings from the set.

My trie structure is as follows:

```
class TrieNode {

    char value;  // character stored at the node
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children;  // list of all children
    boolean isLeaf; // boolean to check if node has no children
    int count; // number of strings inserted below the current node

}
```

While inserting strings in my trie, I increment the `count` variable for a trienode every time it is encountered during insertion.

Now, my task is to retrieve kth lexicographically smallest string from the trie. In order to achieve that, I use the following function:

```
public String findKth(int k) {
    int current_rank = 0;
    String result = "";  // this will be the kth smallest string
    char c = 'a';  // temporary variable to crawl trie in order (a to z)
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> child = root.getChildren(); // root is the root node of my trie
    while (current_rank < k) {
        if (child.containsKey(c)) { // look at this node
            if(child.get(c).count + current_rank < k) { // look at siblings
                current_rank += child.get(c).count;
                c = (char) ((int)c + 1);
            } else { // follow the subtree of this node
                result += c;
                child = child.get(c).getChildren();
                c = 'a';
            }
        } else { // search for next character in order (a-z)
            c = (char) ((int)c + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, I am not able to generate result. Sometimes, my program is stuck in infinite loop or it gives incorrect results. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Kth lexicographically smallest" exactly by giving example inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing one line. Terrible terrible mistake. I am posting incase someone else finds this useful.

```
public String findKth(int k) {
    int current_rank = 0;
    String result = "";
    char c = 'a';
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> child = root.getChildren();
    while (current_rank < k) {
        if (child.containsKey(c)) {
            if(child.get(c).count + current_rank < k) {
                current_rank += child.get(c).count;
                c = (char) ((int)c + 1);
            } else {
                current_rank+=1;  //I WAS MISSING THIS LINE
                result += c;
                child = child.get(c).getChildren();
                c = 'a';
            }
        } else {
            c = (char) ((int)c + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the gist of code I am using to retrieve kth smallest string from my trie - https://gist.github.com/bit1/f67d8de6286e8462180a

Answer (score 0):

When you are surprised that code is stuck in a loop look at the loop and ask yourself *how could this loop carry on forever?*.

```
    while (current_rank < k) {
        if (child.containsKey(c)) { // look at this node
            if (child.get(c).count + current_rank < k) { // look at siblings
                current_rank += child.get(c).count;
                c = (char) ((int) c + 1);
            } else { // follow the subtree of this node
                result += c;
                child = child.get(c).getChildren();
                c = 'a';
            }
        } else { // search for next character in order (a-z)
            c = (char) ((int) c + 1);
        }
    }
```

Obviously this can loop indefinitely on a node with no children while `c` get incremented off into the sunset.

Try something like:

```
    while (current_rank < k && c <= 'z') {
```

Here's a working implementation of a `TrieMap` for reference. Take a look at the `State` class that allows you to step out of the tree and return to the same state you were in when you stepped in.

```
/**
 * Implementation of a Trie structure.
 *
 * A Trie is a compact form of tree that takes advantage of common prefixes to the keys.
 *
 * A normal HashSet will take the key and compute a hash from it, this hash will be used to locate the value through
 * various methods but usually some kind of bucket system is used. The memory footprint resulting becomes something like
 * O(k*n) where k is the average width of the key.
 *
 * A Trie structure essentially combines all common prefixes into a single key. For example, holding the strings A, AB,
 * ABC and ABCD will only take enough space to record the presence of ABCD. The presence of the others will be recorded
 * as flags within the record of ABCD structure at zero cost. Smilarly, ABCDEF and ABCDEG
 * will share the ABCDE root.
 *
 * This structure is useful for holding similar strings such as product IDs or credit card numbers.
 *
 * This implementation does NOT allow null as key or value.
 *
 * NB: The keys to the EntrySet are actually Strings disguised as K type. If this causes issues, use the
 * keyFactory constructor.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 *
 * @param <K> - The type of the key - must implement `CharSequence`.
 * @param <V> - The type of the value.
 *
 */
public class TrieMap<K extends CharSequence, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

  /**
   * Map each character to a sub-trie.
   *
   * Could replace this with a 256 entry array of Tries but this will handle multi-byte character sets and I can discard
   * empty maps.
   *
   * Maintained at null until needed (for better memory footprint).
   *
   */
  private Map<Character, TrieMap<K, V>> children = null;
  // Store the map contents at this node of the tree. A null value means there is no value here.
  private V value = null;
  // My key factory for the EntrySet keys. Defaults to a String key.
  private final KeyFactory<K> keyFactory;

  // Message for null.
  private static final String NoNullsPlease = "A Trie cannot hold nulls!";
  // Message for type failure.
  private static final String KeyIsCharSequencePlease = "Key must be a CharSequence!";

  // Without keyFactory constructor - defaults to String keys.
  public TrieMap() {
    this.keyFactory = StringKeyFactory;
  }

  // With keyFactory constructor.
  public TrieMap(KeyFactory keyFactory) {
    this.keyFactory = keyFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Set the value to a new setting and return the old one.
   *
   * @param newValue
   * @return old value.
   */
  private V setValue(V newValue) {
    // Protect agains nulls.
    ensureNotNull(newValue);
    V old = value;
    value = newValue;
    return old;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new set of children.
   *
   * I've always wanted to name a method something like this.
   */
  private void makeChildren() {
    if (children == null) {
      // Use a TreeMap to ensure sorted iteration.
      children = new TreeMap<>();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Finds the TrieMap that "should" contain the key.
   *
   * @param key
   *
   * The key to find.
   *
   * @param grow
   *
   * Set to true to grow the Trie to fit the key if necessary.
   *
   * @return
   *
   * The sub Trie that "should" contain the key or null if key was not found and grow was false.
   */
  private TrieMap<K, V> find(CharSequence key, boolean grow) {
    if (key.length() == 0) {
      // Found it!
      return this;
    } else {
      // Not at end of string.
      if (grow) {
        // Grow the tree.
        makeChildren();
      }
      // Allow children == null to stop the search.
      if (children != null) {
        // Ask the kids.
        char ch = key.charAt(0);
        TrieMap<K, V> child = children.get(ch);
        if (child == null && grow) {
          // Make the child.
          child = new TrieMap<>(keyFactory);
          // Store the child.
          children.put(ch, child);
        }
        // Allow child == null to stop the search.
        if (child != null) {
          // Find it in the child.
          return child.find(key.subSequence(1, key.length()), grow);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;

  }

  /**
   *
   * Add a new value to the map.
   *
   * Time footprint = O(s.length).
   */
  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    // Protect agains nulls.
    ensureNotNull(key, value);
    // Find it and set its value -- passing grow = true ensures we return something.
    return find(key, true).setValue(value);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value at the specified key position.
   *
   * @param k - The key to use.
   *
   */
  @Override
  public V get(Object k) {
    // Protect agains nulls.
    ensureNotNull(k);
    V got = null;
    // Must be a CharSequence.
    if (k instanceof CharSequence) {
      CharSequence key = (CharSequence) k;
      // Find its place but don't grow.
      TrieMap<K, V> it = find(key, false);
      if (it != null) {
        // Found it.
        got = it.value;
      }
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(KeyIsCharSequencePlease);
    }
    return got;
  }

  /**
   * Remove the value at the specified location.
   *
   * @param k - The key to use.
   */
  @Override
  public V remove(Object k) {
    // Protect agains nulls.
    ensureNotNull(k);
    V old = null;
    if (k instanceof CharSequence) {
      CharSequence key = (CharSequence) k;
      // Find it.
      TrieMap<K, V> it = find(key, false);
      if (it != null) {
        // Record it.
        old = it.value;
        // Remove it.
        it.value = null;
      }
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(KeyIsCharSequencePlease);
    }
    return old;
  }

  /**
   * Count the number of values in the structure.
   */
  @Override
  public int size() {
    // If I am a leaf then size increases by 1.
    int size = value != null ? 1 : 0;
    if (children != null) {
      // Add sizes of all my children.
      for (Map.Entry<Character, TrieMap<K, V>> e : children.entrySet()) {
        size += e.getValue().size();
      }
    }
    return size;
  }

  /**
   * Is the tree empty?
   */
  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    // I am empty if I am not a leaf and I have no children
    // (slightly quicker than the AbstractCollection implementation).
    return value == null && (children == null || children.isEmpty());
  }

  // From here on we are really only implementimg Map as efficiently as we can.

  /**
   * Returns all keys as a Set.
   */
  @Override
  public Set<K> keySet() {
    // Wrap me in a TrieSet.
    return new TrieSet<>((TrieMap<K, Object>) this);
  }

  /**
   * Does the map contain the specified key.
   *
   * @param o - The key to lookup.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean containsKey(Object o) {
    // Protect agains nulls.
    ensureNotNull(o);
    if (o instanceof CharSequence) {
      // Find wihout growing.
      TrieMap<K, V> it = find((CharSequence) o, false);
      if (it != null) {
        return it.value != null;
      }
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(KeyIsCharSequencePlease);
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Clear down completely.
   */
  @Override
  public void clear() {
    children = null;
    value = null;
  }

  /**
   * Return a list of key/value pairs.
   */
  @Override
  public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    return new EntrySet<>(this);
  }

  /**
   * Check v must not be null.
   *
   * Throws exception or returns.
   */
  private static void ensureNotNull(Object... v) {
    // Protect against adding nulls.
    for (Object o : v) {
      if (o == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(NoNullsPlease);
      }
    }
  }

  // Package private because TrieSet uses this class.
  static class EntrySet<K extends CharSequence, V> extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> implements Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    // The map.
    final TrieMap<K, V> map;

    EntrySet(TrieMap<K, V> map) {
      this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
      return new EnrySetIterator<>(map);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return map.size();
    }

    // The core iterator - all others use this.
    private static class EnrySetIterator<K extends CharSequence, V> implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
      // Current state of the search.
      private State<K, V> state;
      // Next Entry to deliver.
      private Entry<K, V> next = null;
      // The key factory.
      final KeyFactory<K> keyFactory;

      // The current state of the iteration.
      private static class State<K extends CharSequence, V> {
        // The key to the current head TrieMap.
        final CharSequence head;
        // The iterator across all sub-characters of this head.
        final Iterator<Character> ci;
        // The map I am working on.
        final TrieMap<K, V> map;
        // The parent state. Allows me to stack the states.
        final State<K, V> parent;

        private State(State<K, V> parent, CharSequence newHead, TrieMap<K, V> map) {
          // Make a sub-state.
          this.head = newHead;
          Map<Character, TrieMap<K, V>> children = map.children;
          // children can be empty.
          if (children != null) {
            ci = children.keySet().iterator();
          } else {
            // Make an empty one.
            ci = Collections.<Character>emptyList().iterator();
          }
          // Keep track of map and parent.
          this.map = map;
          this.parent = parent;
        }

      }

      private EnrySetIterator(State<K, V> parent, CharSequence head, TrieMap<K, V> map) {
        this.keyFactory = map.keyFactory;
        state = new State<>(parent, head, map);
      }

      public EnrySetIterator(TrieMap<K, V> map) {
        // Start at the root with an empty key.
        this(null, "", map);
        // Special case when "" is in the set.
        if (map.value != null) {
          // Prime the next immediately.
          next = new Entry<>(keyFactory.toK(""), map);
        }
      }

      // Become my parent.
      private boolean stepOut() {
        boolean finished = true;
        if (state != null) {
          // Up one.
          state = state.parent;
          // Not finished.
          finished = false;
        }
        return finished;
      }

      // Become my inner child. :)
      private void stepIn(Character ch, TrieMap<K, V> child) {
        state = new State<>(state, new StringBuilder(state.head).append(ch), child);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
        boolean finished = false;
        // Carry on 'till we've found a next or we've finished.
        while (next == null && state != null && !finished) {
          // Step forward through the child list.
          Character ch = state.ci.hasNext() ? state.ci.next() : null;
          if (ch != null) {
            TrieMap<K, V> it = state.map.children.get(ch);
            if (it.value != null) {
              next = new Entry<>(keyFactory.toK(new StringBuilder(state.head).append(ch)), it);
            }
            // Step in to that one.
            stepIn(ch, it);
          } else {
            // Child iterator exhausted. Step up to parent.
            finished = stepOut();
          }
        }
        return next != null;
      }

      @Override
      public Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
        Entry<K, V> it = null;
        if (hasNext()) {
          it = next;
          next = null;
        }
        return it;
      }

      @Override
      public void remove() {
        // Remove the empty string entry from the current map 'cause that's us.
        state.map.remove(keyFactory.toK(""));
      }

    }
  }

  /**
   * An entry.
   *
   * @param <V>
   *
   * The type of the value.
   */
  private static class Entry<K extends CharSequence, V>
          implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private final TrieMap<K, V> map;

    Entry(K key, TrieMap<K, V> map) {
      this.key = key;
      this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
      return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
      return map.value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V newValue) {
      // Protect agains nulls.
      ensureNotNull(newValue);
      V oldValue = map.value;
      map.value = newValue;
      return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!(o instanceof Entry)) {
        return false;
      }
      Entry e = (Entry) o;
      return key.equals(e.getKey()) && map.value.equals(e.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return key.hashCode() ^ map.value.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return key + "=" + map.value;
    }

  }

  // Key factories.
  public interface KeyFactory<K extends CharSequence> {
    // Make a key from this sequence.
    public K toK(CharSequence c);

  }

  public static class StringKeyFactory implements KeyFactory<String> {
    @Override
    public String toK(CharSequence c) {
      return c.toString();
    }

  }
  // They are all idempotent so we can pre-build them.
  public static final KeyFactory StringKeyFactory = new StringKeyFactory();

  public static class StringBuilderKeyFactory implements KeyFactory<StringBuilder> {
    @Override
    public StringBuilder toK(CharSequence c) {
      return new StringBuilder(c);
    }

  }
  // They are all idempotent so we can pre-build them.
  public static final KeyFactory StringBuilderKeyFactory = new StringBuilderKeyFactory();

  public static class StringBufferKeyFactory implements KeyFactory<StringBuffer> {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer toK(CharSequence c) {
      return new StringBuffer(c);
    }

  }
  // They are all idempotent so we can pre-build them.
  public static final KeyFactory StringBufferKeyFactory = new StringBufferKeyFactory();

  public static <V> Map<String, V> newStringMap() {
    return new TrieMap<>(StringKeyFactory);
  }

  public static <V> Map<StringBuilder, V> newStringBuilderMap() {
    return new TrieMap<>(StringBuilderKeyFactory);
  }

  public static <V> Map<StringBuffer, V> newStringBufferMap() {
    return new TrieMap<>(StringBufferKeyFactory);
  }

  // Testing.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      TrieMap<String, String> t = new TrieMap<>();
      String[] tests = {
        "",
        "A",
        "AB",
        "A",
        "AB",
        "ABCDEFG",
        "ZYX",
        "a",
        "zyx",
        "0123456789",
        "0123456789A"
      };
      for (String s : tests) {
        String added = t.put(s, s);
        System.out.println("Added '" + s
                + "'\tResult: " + added
                + "\tSize: " + t.size()
                + "\tContains: " + t.containsKey(s));
      }
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);
      System.out.println("Removing: " + "0123456789");
      t.remove("0123456789");
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = t.entrySet().iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> e = i.next();
        if (e.getKey().equals("A")) {
          System.out.println("Removing: " + "A");
          i.remove();
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);

      String[] tests2 = {
        "",
        "A",
        "ABCD",
        "ZYXWVU"
      };
      for (String s : tests2) {
        System.out.println("'" + s + "'\tContains: " + t.containsKey(s));
      }
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);

      Set<String> keys = t.keySet();
      System.out.println("Keys: " + keys);

      Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = t.entrySet();
      System.out.println("Entries: " + entries);

      t.clear();
      System.out.println("Clear: " + t);
      Map<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> m = TrieMap.<StringBuilder>newStringBuilderMap();
      m.put(new StringBuilder(""), new StringBuilder(""));
      m.put(new StringBuilder("0"), new StringBuilder("0"));
      m.put(new StringBuilder("01"), new StringBuilder("01"));
      m.put(new StringBuilder("012"), new StringBuilder("012"));
      System.out.println("Entries: " + m.entrySet());
      for (Map.Entry<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> e : m.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey().toString() + " key is a " + e.getKey().getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(e.getValue().toString() + " value is a " + e.getKey().getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

The `TrieSet` it uses internally looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of a Trie Set of a CharSequence.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @param <K>
 */
public class TrieSet<K extends CharSequence> extends AbstractSet<K> implements Set<K> {
  // Hold a TrieMap<Object> and always put v in it.
  private final Object v = new Object();
  // My backing map.
  private final TrieMap<K, Object> map;

  // Start empty.
  public TrieSet() {
    this(new TrieMap<K, Object>());
  }

  // Start empty.
  public TrieSet(TrieMap.KeyFactory keyFactory) {
    this(new TrieMap<K, Object>(keyFactory));
  }

  // Wrap an existing map.
  // Package private because I expect only TrieMap will want a Set wrapper.
  // Used by TrieMap to return its keyset.
  TrieSet(TrieMap<K, Object> map) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<K> iterator() {
    return new TrieSetIterator<>(map);
  }

  // My iterator feeds off an EntryIterator from the TrieMap.
  private static class TrieSetIterator<K extends CharSequence> implements Iterator<K> {
    // Keep an Entry iterator.
    private final Iterator<Map.Entry<K, Object>> i;

    public TrieSetIterator(TrieMap<K, Object> map) {
      // Make an EntrySet and grab its iterator.
      i = new TrieMap.EntrySet<>(map).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public K next() {
      K it = null;
      if (i.hasNext()) {
        // Return just the key from the Entry.
        it = i.next().getKey();
      }
      return it;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      // Same as the entry iterator.
      return i.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      // Ripple up to the entry iterator.
      i.remove();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(K k) {
    return map.put(k, v) == null;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return map.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return o instanceof CharSequence && map.containsKey((K) o);
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nStrings = 0;
    int nChars = 0;
    try {
      TrieSet t = new TrieSet();
      String[] tests = {
        "",
        "A",
        "AB",
        "A",
        "AB",
        "ABCDEFG",
        "ZYX",
        "a",
        "zyx",
        "0123456789",
        "0123456789A"
      };
      for (String s : tests) {
        boolean added = t.add(s);
        System.out.println("Added '" + s + "'\tResult: " + added + "\tSize: " + t.size() + "\tContains: " + t.contains(s));
        //System.out.println("Trie: " + t);
      }

      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);
      System.out.println("Removing: 0123456789");
      t.remove("0123456789");
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);

      String[] tests2 = {
        "",
        "A",
        "ABCD",
        "ZYXWVU"
      };
      for (String s : tests2) {
        System.out.println("'" + s + "'\tContains: " + t.contains(s));
      }
      System.out.println("Trie: " + t);
      // Remove
      TrieSet t2 = new TrieSet();
      t2.addAll(Arrays.<String>asList(tests2));
      t.removeAll(t2);
      System.out.println("Removed them: " + t);

      // Remove while iterating.
      Iterator<String> i = t.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        String n = i.next();
        if (n.equals("AB")) {
          i.remove();
          System.out.println("Removed: " + n);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Finished: " + t);
      // Test to destrunction.
      t.clear();
      System.out.println("Testing to destruction: ");
      for (long n = 0;; n++) {
        String s = Long.toString(n);
        nStrings += 1;
        nChars += s.length();
        t.add(s);
        if (nStrings % 100 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Added: " + nStrings);
        }
      }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      System.out.println("Strings: " + nStrings);
      System.out.println("Chars: " + nChars);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Lets say that the dataset is such that the situation you have mentioned will never arise. This means that, if I will encounter a leaf node, it will be guaranteed that `current_rank` is greater than or equal to `k`.

Comment: @Bhoot - All you need is `child.containsKey(c)` always returning `false` and your loop never ends. Fix that first.

Comment: I am making sure that this situation will never arise. There will never be an invalid query over the tree. If you are upto it, please suggest an independent way to retrieve the kth smallest string, without considering the code I have mentioned.

Comment: @Bhoot - Implement [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: Sadly, the size of string set is of the order of 10^7. Therefore, O(nlogn) is unacceptable.

Comment: @Bhoot - You should be able to traverse your tree and maintain a stack to keep track of where you are. That way you could create an `Iterator` that does not need to build a `List`.

Comment: @Bhoot - See edits for a full `TrieMap` implementation as example of walkin the `Trie` with an `Iterator`.

Comment: Thank you. Let me go through this and get back to you.